# What is a "liste de naissance"?

Tags: sens

I keep seeing this term around Amazon's French site and I can't make sense of it nor find a translation for it. I feel like it's going to be really obvious once someone tells me.

Comment: [Not restricted to France](http://www.amazon.com/gp/baby/homepage?ie=UTF8&cid=&qid=1414400025&type=baby), not typically French nor restricted to [births](http://www.amazon.com/gp/wedding/homepage/?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-auto-sparkle&pf_rd_r=03R8Z3Y3QTWCV4XE98PY&pf_rd_p=1955351802&pf_rd_t=301&pf_rd_i=wedding%20registry&qid=1414400355)...

Comment: I expect the question will be closed because it is not really related to French language as defined in the FAQ. Lots of shops, not only on line (this existed well before the Internet came into existence), and not only in France, offer the possibility to organize [wish lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish_list) for special occasions, births, weddings, anniversaries, birthdays, etc., thus creating a captive customer base and sparing the happy recipients from getting duplicate gifts.

Comment: Seems in the US the usual term for such a list is [registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridal_registry).

Comment: @Laure I don't get it. How is this question not related to the French language? I'd never heard this expression, but I guessed its meaning immediately (by analogy with *liste de mariage*) — this is anecdotal evidence that this is a natural linguistic construction (an aspect of the *génie de la langue*) and thus squarely on-topic. The existence of an English translation does not disqualify (and it even isn't a literal translation). To those who are voting to close as a dictionary lookup request: in which dictionary did you find this expression?

Comment: @Gilles Thank you!!!! I was thinking that but hadn't quite yet composed the argument so comprehensively.

Comment: @Gilles It's  easy to find a translation for *liste de naissance*, I asked for it to be closed referring to **Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first.** after I found it on linguee. Didn't take me 5 second. Also when you type *liste de naissance* in a search engine you find a very large number of commercial sites explaining what it is and how to create one. A definition  on [l'internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/liste-de-naissance/): first hit when you type *"liste de naissance" definition*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "liste de naissance" is an e-card (or paper card or a web page) in which you actually write a list of items or potentially gifts that you find usefull for your baby.

It's meant to be given to your family and relatives in order to avoid any duplicate gifts.

**Edit :** 
Amazon seems to have a service that allows you to build such a list with the Amazon store items. It's like making a shopping cart full of items that you share to your relatives in order that they will buy it for your baby.